# How to get sub-string for a string using pattern analysis?

Tags: command-line, regex

I want to get sub-string of any string using pattern analysis. Example String:

```xml
<string module name="Jai" fathername="S.S. Khan" phone="1234">
    <address complete="startz us" />
    <worker company="Delta star" />
<string module name="Jai" phone="1234">
<string module name="Jai" value="" phone="1234">
    <status now="single />
<string module name="Jai" email= "Jai@email.com" value="" phone="1234">
    <address complete="startz us" />
    <worker company="Delta star" />
```

I want the following values (`grep`ed by `phone`):

```
string module name="Jai" fathername="S.S. Khan"
string module name="Jai"
string module name="Jai" value=""
string module name="Jai" email= "Jai@email.com" value=""
```

If I run the following command it returns only those rows which have `phone`:

```
cat file.txt | grep phone.
```

To overcome this I am running:

```
cat file.txt | grep phone | sed 's/phone=".*"/phone=""/g' | grep -v phone`
```

It works but I want to do this with exactly pattern analysis.

Can anyone help or guide me how can I do so?

Comment: You can try this, `sed -e 's/<.*\/>//g;s/phone=".*"//;s/[<>]//g' file.txt`. If I understand you correctly. Also this like question should be asked on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you want to use regular expressions to do your pattern analysis. You can try this `perl` oneliner:

```
cat file.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /(string module name=.*?)phone.*/'
```

- `perl -ne` will analyze your `file.txt` line by line
- then it will print only the content of the pattern between the `(...)`